# Vue.js instant search - console error - unable to invoke .use on InstantSearch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, instantsearch.js

I’ve followed the guide for installing vue instantsearch (4.3) in my Vue.js (3.0) application.

In my main.js file, I have the following -

```
import InstantSearch from 'vue-instantsearch/vue3/es'

Vue.use(InstantSearch);
```

Here’s the exact console error -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'use')
```

This is the code that’s provided in the guide so I’m unsure why I’m receiving this error.

Comment: You need to `import Vue from 'vue'` prior to this, else `Vue` will be undefined, hence your error.

Comment: Yeah I've already done that above. I just didn't include it in the code. Here's the full file - ```import { Vue, createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import InstantSearch from 'vue-instantsearch/vue3/es'

Vue.use(InstantSearch);

createApp(App).mount('#app')```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, vue 3 now uses create app so below would work best

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import Root from './App.vue'
import InstantSearch from 'vue-instantsearch/vue3/es'

const app = createApp(Root)
    .use(InstantSearch)
    .mount('#app')
```

Comment: As long as you're calling app() somewhere this is the solution.